# Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: postgresql, maven, liquibase

Im trying to change a project a bit, by upgrading it with Liquibase. Its a Java EE project. So im using the liquibase-maven-plugin.

So far i have in my pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!--  Another Error: plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration..-->
                        <!-- <phase>process-resources</phase> <goals> <goal>update</goal> </goals> -->
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

which already includes a Driver:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

the liquibase.properties file has the url, username, password, the changeLogFile-Path and the driver:

```
#liquibase.properties
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
```

But it does not have a classpath for the driver. Do I need the classpath as well?

The changelog.xml has a simple changeset which creates a table, just to test liquibase for the beginning.

But I dont come so far, because when I run the project with

```
mvn liquibase:update
```

Im getting this error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:2.0.5:update (default-cli) on project PROJECT: Error setting up or running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver

I cant see the point.. The driver has been already been used before with the project. So why cant liquibase find it?

**EDIT**

When i edit my configuration in the pom.xml by adding the driver tag it works:

```
            <configuration>
                <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
            </configuration>
```

before that my driver was specified in liquibase.properties, which should actually work as well.

maybe someone can tell me how the liquibase.properties file should look like if i´d like to keep the driver in the properties file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit:**

The problem was resolved by replacing
`driver: org.postgresql.Driver` with `driver=org.postgresql.Driver` in the liquibase.properties file.

---

**Original Answer:**

You have added the postgresql driver as a dependency of your webapp. But when maven plugins run, they have their own classpath, which is different to your webapp. So you need to include a dependency on the JDBC driver for the plugin itself (same applies to other plugins, e.g. jetty-maven-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!--  Another Error: plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration..-->
            <!-- <phase>process-resources</phase> <goals> <goal>update</goal> </goals> -->
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: No, thats not the problem. The error still appears even if i add it a second time. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Weird, I just tried your sample using the properties file, and it picks up the driver fine for me (even without specifying the dependency on postgres within the plugin). Maybe try delete the postgres JAR and liquibase plugin from your local maven repo so it gets re-downloaded? Also try specifying the driver using an '=', `driver=org.postgresql.Driver`. Otherwise I'm out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: THANKS!!!! It really annoys me when something works or doesnt work and I dont understand why. It was just the simple `":"` instead of `"="` in `driver=org.postgresql.Driver`. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Following plugin configuration worked for me.

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the liquibase gradle plugin, then you can add this runtime dependency in the build.gradle file to avoid this error.

```
dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.24"
}
```